# How to fix " Div background color not changing from white to transparent" in ipad air (Safari browser)

Tags: html, css, safari

I am working on header for a website. The functionality is as such that the transparent header will set on top of page on a background image. When we scroll down the header will turn into white and while scrolling up when we reaches top header will again transparent.

Working fine everywhere except safari ipad air. Whats happening is when i return to top, instead of transparent color comes out to be sometimes black sometimes grey.

If any other color instead of transparent is given, it works fine

```
.global__header {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;  
}

.global__header--white {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.global__header {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;  
}
```